# iOS In app purchase "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" error

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I know that it usually takes 24-36 hours before an in app purchase becomes available for a new app. But I have a problem where an approved IAP is unavailable even after several days.

It works in the sandbox environment and I've used the same code in other projects, so I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with my code.

I know I can get the product correctly since I display the price in local currency. But when I begin the purchase I get the "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" error.

Does anyone else have problems with this recently?

It seems to be a lot of strange errors in iTunes Connect, Xcode and AppStore since the release of iOS 11.